# Generate lazy Stream from method call in Java

Tags: java, java-stream, lazy-evaluation

For example I have a method `List<A> getA()`, and I want to get a `Stream<A>` elements of which are the result of `getA()` call, but in such way that `getA()` will be called only when stream will be terminated with a collector. I have a couple ideas like:

```
Stream.of(() -> getA()).map(Supplier::get).flatMap(Collection::stream);
```

or

```
Stream.generate(() -> getA()).limit(1).flatMap(Collection::stream);
```

but maybe someone knows a more convenient approach. Thank you.

Comment: First approach looks good already :)

Comment: Probably need a reactive library such as Spring WebFlux.

Comment: No need to add a reactive library, Java's native `Stream`s are fine. As @sp00m mentions, the first approach is fine. It will create a lazy stream of 1 item (a `List`) that will be exploded in several items

Comment: `StreamSupport.stream(() -> getA().spliterator(), 0, false)` seems more readable, but the drawback(need to provide characteristic of the spliterator) is large also.